How to create a new column showing which occurrence of an event (1st time, 2nd time, ect..) based on a Date column in Power Query
I have a dataset with an event ID, a date, and an event value. Each event can occur multiple times at different dates. I want to create a column telling me which occurrence a certain ID-Date combination I'm looking at. The end goal would be to look at event value avg on 1st, 2nd, 3rd occurrence and so on.
Example Data:
Data Example
What I'm trying to get:
Wanted Data
I'm fairly new to this so I'm really lost, any help is appreciated.
I'm honestly not sure what to try!

In the Power Query Editor: Transform Data => Advanced Editor
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table19"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Event ID", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),

//add index column to retain original order
    #"Add Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type","Index",0,1,Int64.Type),

//Group by "Event ID"
//  Then add index column to each subtable
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Add Index", {"Event ID"}, {
        {"all", each Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.Sort(_, {"Date"}),"Occurrence",1,1,Int64.Type)
        ,type table [Event ID=nullable text, Date=nullable date, Value=nullable number, Index=nullable number, Occurrence=nullable number]}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Event ID"}),

//Re-expand the grouped tables
//  then re-sort to original order
    #"Expanded all" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "all",{"Event ID", "Date", "Value", "Index", "Occurrence"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded all",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),

//remove now superfluous index column
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"



I think you can also use Index to create slices to count occurrence:

Results look like this:

let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content],
  AddOriginalIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "OriginalIndex", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
  SortByDate = Table.Sort(AddOriginalIndex, {{"Date", Order.Ascending}}),
  AddIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(SortByDate, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
  AddSlices = Table.AddColumn(AddIndex, "Slice", each List.Transform({0..[Index]}, each SortByDate[Event ID]{_})),
  CountOccurences = (eventList as list, event as text) =>List.Sum(List.Transform(eventList,  each if _ = event then 1 else 0)),
  AddOccurences = Table.AddColumn(AddSlices, "Occurrence", each CountOccurences([Slice], [Event ID])),
  SortByOriginalIndex = Table.Sort(AddOccurences, {{"OriginalIndex", Order.Ascending}})
in
  SortByOriginalIndex

